# below command doesn't align nodes as expected (beamer and tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

I want to place several nodes aligned to the left on a beamer slide. I use the following simple example:

```
\documentclass[xetex,mathserif,serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary[positioning]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node (a) [anchor = west] {first node};%
    \node (b) [anchor = west, below = of a.west] {second node};%
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And the result is

[image]

While I expect the two lines to be align to the left. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

`below=of othernode` sets `anchor=north`, and that takes precedence over your `anchor=west`. Swap the order and it works as expected.

Note that you don't generally want to specify the driver (here `xetex`), packages like `graphicx` can figure that out themselves, so I removed that key from the class options.
Also, `beamer` (and `tikz`) loads `graphicx`, so you don't have to add that explicitly. And for `\usetikzlibrary` you should have `{}` not `[]` around the list of libraries I believe, or at least that's how it's given in the manual.

```
\documentclass[mathserif,serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node (a) [anchor = west] {first node};%
    \node (b) [below = of a.west,anchor = west] {second node};%
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```